# T-Sql @@Identity

Tags: t-sql, identity

Does someone know how can I return the `@@Identity` when using T-Sql?

Something like this:

```
set @Sql = "insert into table....values()..."
exec @sql
return @@Identity
```

Comment: What do you mean return @@Identity? From where? And do you actually need @@Identity or scope_identity?

Comment: @user - So if a trigger on the original table inserts into another table with an identity column you need the identity for that second table?

Comment: @user, What Martin is getting at is that there are several methods of returning the identity value, (@@Identity, Scope_Identity() function, etc.) and these alternatives were created because of issues when using @@Identity, which is the oldest of them. You should (unless you already are aware of this) read up on these methods and ensure that @@Identity is really the best one for your application.

Comment: If you post code or XML, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: Under no circumstances woudl I ever use @@identity for this. You will eventually have data integrity issues because there are circunmstances where @@identity returns the WRONG value. Use the output clause or scope_identity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO TableName (Field1, Field2, Field3) VALUES (1, 2, 3);
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```

This is a multi-statement batch, so I'm not sure that every client library will return values the same way; in classic ADO, for example, it's possible that you might need to advance to the next recordset before you can read the value. But if you're using ADO.NET, I know that you can just use [ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx) on the whole string above, and it will return your `SCOPE_IDENTITY` value just fine.

Caution: ADO.NET will return the value as a [`decimal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.aspx), not an [`int`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.aspx) like you might expect. This is because [`SCOPE_IDENTITY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx), for whatever reason, is typed as `numeric(38,0)`. So you either need to cast the ExecuteScalar result to `decimal` before you cast it to `int`, or you need to `SELECT CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS INT)` (assuming your IDENTITY field is an INT, and not some larger numeric type).

Comment: I would **always** use SCOPE_IDENTITY rather than @@IDENTITY

Comment: I didn't even know about `SCOPE_IDENTITY`, but it looks like you're right. From a couple minutes of skimming, it looks like would take some exotic circumstances (like INSERT triggers that do more INSERTs into other tables) to make `@@IDENTITY` wrong; but still, you're right, `SCOPE_IDENTITY` is the Right Thing. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 6):

It looks like one of your implicit requirements is the execution of dynamic SQL. While I'd advise against this, you can accomplish what you're looking for with this:

```
set @Sql = 'insert into table....values()...; select SCOPE_IDENTITY()'
exec(@Sql)
```

Answer (score 4):

Like this:

```
INSERT INTO Table(...)
OUTPUT INSERTED.IdColumn
VALUES(...)
```

Comment: This will work in 2008 and above. And the beauty of it is you can reutrn other fields as well if you need them.

Answer (score 3):

Append ";select @@identity" to your insert statement:

```
insert into tab (x,y,z) values (a,b,c); select @@identity
```

The returned value is the ID (use ExecuteScalar)

Comment: Please note that using @@identity will yield incorrect results if you have an insert trigger which inserts rows into another table with an identity column. It's safer and more future-proof to use SCOPE_IDENTITY as Ken suggests. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
Insert into Table(Col2, Col3) 
output inserted.Id
values ('xyz', 'abc')
```

Where `Id` is your Identity field